# Getting 0 when trying to get the offset top value of element onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm working on the project that has more than one iframes. The main iframe has the page and the page contains child iframe that also have page contents.

Inside the child iframe I have the tabs, each tab have the page contents that are loaded dynamically from the server.

I'm trying to get the offset top value of a div element using offset().top from screen top when page onload. It returns some value when reloading the child iframe using 'Reload iframe', but it returns '0' when reloading the page.

I'm attaching herewith the image what I'am trying to do, please check, if I'am not clearly explained my problem above.

[image: Problem Description Image]

I tried this code and placed this code inside $(document).ready(){}, its working fine when reloading the particular iframe. But returns 0 on load.

```
var $stored_selector = $('#displayMedsdetail');
var offset = $stored_selector.offset(), remaining_height;
console.log(offset.top);
```

Can anyone please help me find out why offset().top returns 0 when reloading the page?

Comment: Which event are u using to get `offset` value....? Right event is important otherwise you will get undefined or 0 value.

Comment: @KickyTrick when are you calling the above JS code? It could be that the iframe is not loaded.

Comment: @TusharAcharekar, it seems writing an answer without your page codes be hard but make sure you write your code in `document.ready` in the child iframe and if it dose not worked for a test do this: Write your getting offset code in an `function` and run it with a timer in `document.ready` like this:  `setTimeout(function(){ getOffset(); }, 3000);`
and let me know its result.

Comment: I already tried to get the offset value by placing the code inside document ready, but still it returns value 0.

Answer (score 3):

Use .contents() to get to iFrame's DOM.

Here's an example of some code I used before:

```
var content=$("iframe").contents().find('body').html();
```

You can probably rewrite it to get the div element and the offset of it.

Comment: I'm trying to get the value from the page of child iframe.

Comment: yea, you should be able to get the data of the sidebar through the DOM. You just need to find the correct path to it so you can retrieve and later modify its data.

Comment: Pls check the edit, the code which I have edited gives the offset value say if 50px from top but the same thing returns 0px when page load. This is what the problem the same code gives diferent value. I need to get the offset().top value of the element on page load.

Comment: ok, so as far as I can tell from your edit when you reload the Iframe itself it works fine, but when you reload the whole page it sets it to 0. This probably means your code of getting the Iframe data is correct, but there is something in your page which on reload overwrites the data that you are trying to get or makes it so the data isn't executed anymore. So I think you best debug in which order everything is loaded in, to see whether everything is executed and if nothing is overwritten. Simplest way is to put a lot of alerts between all your lines of code to see what happens.

Comment: I tried to find out in all way, but I could not find out where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can't help you any further on this matter, there must be something going wrong there and not in the part where you retrieve the data good luck and let me know when you fix the problem and what the exact problem was.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're not trying to grab info from an iFrame. Because iFrames are usually not designed for anything else other than viewing it. That means no editing it and no grabbing of any information. So therefore as far as I know, there is no way to grab any information from inside an iFrame using JS.

As for why you can't read the top offset of the iFrame that you may have. Then that has most likely to do with timing. Some problems may be solved when you choose `$(document).ready()` in conjunction with `setTimeout()` and in many cases even 0 ms is good enough. Since there is no code to see, it's really difficult to say what the problem may be.

Comment: _"Because iFrames are usually not designed for anything else other than viewing it. That means no editing it and no grabbing of any information. So therefore as far as I know, there is no way to grab any information from inside an iFrame using JS."_ This is completely incorrect. If an `iframe` is sourced from the same domain as your host page, you have _full_ access to its DOM and everything in it. If it comes from a different domain, you have no access. It isn't the fact that it's an `iframe` that determines this, it's the domain it comes from.

Comment: Im trying to get the offset value of a element of a page of child element. I'm not trying to get the Iframe values.

I need to set the height to the sidebar div dynamically, for that I want to get the left-side bar DIV element offset top value to calculate with screen.height or documentElementOffsetHeight. So that I can get some height value to give to the sidebar and enable the scrolling.